# Changing attribute values of a tag using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

I want to click on Select Year dropdown and select a year from it. Go to that page and fetch the HTML.
I've written this piece of code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/SoumyaPandey/Desktop/Galytix/Scrapers/data_ingestion/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://investors.aercap.com/results-and-events/financial-results')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_id('year_filter_chosen').click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name('active-result')
```

I'm just starting to work with selenium and got no clue how to proceed further.
I tried to look for the next class after clicking on the dropdown. I want to set the attribute value 'data-option-array-index' to 1 first, open the page, get html. Then keep on changing the value of this attribute.
Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

```
driver.get('https://investors.aercap.com/results-and-events/financial-results')
elem=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#year-filter')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", elem)
selectYear=Select(elem)
selectYear.select_by_index(1)
```

Simply find the element and use Select after you change it's style to display block to access it's values.

Imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

Answer (score 1):

For  tag in selenium there's great Class Select, example provided my colleague in the neighbor answer. But there's also a bit easier way to do it as well, like:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://investors.aercap.com/results-and-events/financial-results')
el = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#year-filter')
time.sleep(3)

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", el)

el.send_keys('2018')

time.sleep(3)

driver.quit()
```